# How to set the data value with Symfony 2.7 and 'choice' elements

Tags: symfony

I have a choice field whose data is not be set on update.

The property is a plain property.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
 protected $demonstratedBefore;
```

The 'Type' sets choice.

```
$builder->add('demonstratedBefore', 'choice', array(
  'choices' => array('No' => FALSE, 'Yes' => TRUE),
  'expanded' => TRUE,
  'multiple' => FALSE,
  'label' => 'Have you demonstrated before?',
  // 2.7 API
  'choices_as_values' => TRUE
));
```

The type class does call 'set defaults' although this is not a default, but an attempt at presenting the stored data in the form:

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
 public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
  $resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'data_class' => 'Unsw\CamsBundle\Entity\Application',
  ));
 }
```

Using the bootstrap template

```
<div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        {{ form_label(form.demonstratedBefore) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 controls">
        {{ form_widget(form.demonstratedBefore,{'attr' : { 'inline' : true }}) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

the following HTML is generated:

```
 <input type="radio" id="application_graduatedSince_0" name="application[graduatedSince]" required="required" value="0" data-bv-field="application[graduatedSince]">
```

The 'selected' attribute is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [symfony issues list](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14377), I added a random 'choice_value' callback

```
$builder->add('demonstratedBefore', 'choice', array(
  'choices' => array('No' => FALSE, 'Yes' => TRUE),
  'expanded' => TRUE,
  'multiple' => FALSE,
  'label' => 'Have you demonstrated before?',
  // 2.7 API
  'choices_as_values' => TRUE,
  'choice_value' => function ($choice) {
      return $choice;
    },
));
```

The rendered html has the checked attribute as required:

```
<input type="radio" id="application_demonstratedBefore_0" name="application[demonstratedBefore]" required="required" value="" checked="checked" data-bv-field="application[demonstratedBefore]">
```

I am not sure if upgrading from 2.7.6 will also resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

If your just trying to set a default value, then you can set it in the entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
*/
 protected $demonstratedBefore = false;
```

this will only set the default when creating a new record, also you should now be able to strip out the 'choice_value' from your form builder.

Comment: I was trying to ask about data value - not default value. Symfony in the way the question is setup does not 'retain the value you set in the form' when you edit.